# jquery slider with textbox input

Tags: jquery, textbox, uislider

I am trying to change value of UI slider from textbox's value but the `slider` method seems to do nothing on the textbox's `change` event. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function () {
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [0, 500],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#MinimumPrice").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#MaximumPrice").val(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $("#MinimumPrice").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        $("#MaximumPrice").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

        //Change slider value from textbox 
        $("#MinimumPrice").change(function () {
            var value = $("#MinimumPrice").val();
            console.log(value);
            $("#slider-range").slider('value', value);
        });
    });
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="Price" class="main_filter" name="filterDiv">
    <h4>Price</h4>
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
    <span class="">
        <br />
        <h4>Price Range</h4>
        <br />
        <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;width:100%;text-align: center;">
            <div class="input-group" style="width: 40%;float: left;">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input id="MinimumPrice" maxlength="6" name="MinimumPrice" style="border:0;width: 50%" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <span style="width: 20%;float: left;">to</span>
            <div class="input-group" style="width: 40%">
                <input id="MaximumPrice" maxlength="6" name="MaximumPrice" style="border:0;width: 50%" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Check the Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MD3mX/1663/)

Comment: please, post also your html (or even better, create a jsFiddle)

Comment: @Dacklf Edited my post. Check now

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#MinimumPrice").on('change', function () {
    var value = $("#MinimumPrice").val();
    console.log(value);
    $("#slider-range").slider('values', 0, value);
});
$("#MaximumPrice").on('change', function () {
    var value = $("#MaximumPrice").val();
    console.log(value);
    $("#slider-range").slider('values', 1, value);
});
```

Comment: Tried. Still it doesn't move the slider on input `change` event

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle so I can check?

Comment: Check edited post. I have created a jsFiddle and textbox input doesn't move the slider

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because jQuery UI depends on jQuery and you are not including the resource. Your code is right.

```
//Change slider value from textbox 
$("#MinimumPrice").on('change', function () {
    var value = $("#MinimumPrice").val();
    $("#slider-range").slider('values', 0, value);
});
$("#MaximumPrice").on('change', function () {
    var value = $("#MaximumPrice").val();
    console.log(value);
    $("#slider-range").slider('values', 1, value);
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jrerx7er/).

**UPDATE**
Just to clarify, you are including [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/) but not [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/).
You can find the hosted library you need [here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js). You can also [download](http://jquery.com/download/) it.

And trying to answer the question about why some parts of your code work and some don't, I really don't know but I guess some jQuery UI functions use pure javascript and don't depend on jQuery.

Comment: Which resource is missing? I have included following references:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Also if Jquery UI slider is working when dragging it through mouse pointer then why not with the input change event?